# Deserialization List to HashMap jackson

Tags: java, list, jackson, hashmap, deserialization

I have an issue regarding serialization/deserialization with jackson.

I have a class with a Map (occupations) like this:

```
public class RoomType implements Comparable<RoomType>, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2310443507411437907L;
  // Key: idUseOccupation, Value: Occupation
  private Map<Long, Occupation> occupations = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 ...
```

and the Getter of this field instead of returning a Map, it's returning a Collection

```
  public Collection<Occupation> getOccupations() {
    return occupations.values();
  }
```

Setter:

```
  public void setOccupations(Map<Long, Occupation> occupations) {
    this.occupations = occupations;
  }
```

So, I have no problem with the serialization, but when I try to deserialize with jackson to a roomType object, I get an error:
`Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token`. Just for testing I have changed the getter from Collection to Map and I checked that it works fine, but I cannot make this change because it will imply multiple changes in lots of classes and it might provoke such a big issues in several applications.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance of seeing an example json please. My guess is that Jackson is seeing thestart of an array, but does not the type. You may need to implemeny your own mapper

Comment: Include setOccupations(..) in the question, and any other convenience methods that affect the internal representation. I suspect that it accepts a LinkedHashMap but the serialized construct is a JSON array.

Comment: I have added the setter @vsfDawg:

`  public void setOccupations(Map<Long, Occupation> occupations) {
    this.occupations = occupations;
  }`

Comment: Jackson will create a JSON array when serializing occupations because the getter produces a Collection. A JSON array cannot be implicitly converted into a Map so Jackson is barking at you when you try to deserialize that same JSON.  You should be able to create a JsonDeserializer for doing the conversion (assuming the Map key can be derived from a given element) and direct Jackson to use this via the @JsonDeserialize annotation on the setter.  You'll have to search Jackson docs and tutorials for specifics.

Comment: @vsfDawg thanks for your answer. I've created my own deserializer and I've used 
 JsonDeserialize as you mentioned and it works. Many thanks.